# I cannot get value from server in Eclipse Milo Client and KepServerEx server

Tags: java, eclipse, opc-ua, milo, kepserverex

I am using Eclipse Milo 0.6.3 and KepServerEx 6. The connection to the server is find.

[Here the server with all groups and tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlsgb.png)

My goal is to get tags value in the Java client and process them;

If I do:
`client.getAddressSpace().getObjectNode(new NodeId(2,"Codesys.CA1.Application.GVL_OPC_Vars.MDD_a_bArrB1000[x]")).browse()`

I get the list of `List<ReferenceDescription> referenceDescriptions` (2000 variables)

But when I try to get the single tag I got an error:

`UaVariableNode node = client.getAddressSpace().getVariableNode(new NodeId(0, "Codesys.CA1.Application.GVL_OPC_Vars.MDD_a_bArrB1000[x].MDD_a_bArrB1000[1]")); DataValue value = node.readValue();`

the Exception trace:

`status=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, description=The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space.`

In the PLC `MDD_a_bArrB0000, MDD_a_bArrB1000, MDD_a_bArrB3000, MDD_a_bArrB4000`  are Arrays.

If someone can help me please in this.

Answer (score 0):

The `NodeId` you are constructing is certainly wrong. Namespace index 0 is reserved for use by the OPC Foundation.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thinks by replying. You are right nodeId is wrong. I tried too: 
`client.getAddressSpace().getObjectNode(new NodeId(2, "Codesys.CA1.Application.GVL_OPC_Vars.MDD_a_bArrB1000[x].MDD_a_bArrB1000[1]"))`

But got the same error"

`UaException: status=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, message=The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space.`

Whate is the correct path to get the tag variable?
Thanks

Comment: That looks correct, but you would have to follow one or more browse calls until you arrive at the Node to be certain. Or you can view it in another client like UaExpert to verify.

Comment: I think the problem come from the KepServerEx . Even UAExpert cannot see the node. I get  **badNodIdUnknown**.